# Single Click Expose

Tags: 16.04, single-user

Is it possible to have single click on the dock icons activate expose by default?

If you have a single window open in ubuntu it doesn't activate expose but if you have multiple windows open it does.  This cause issues when I tried to use expose on several different windows in ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a link to what expose is to your question?

Comment: so, in other words, you want to have such view even if there's only one window of that app open ?

Comment: @LiamWilliam is it expose or scale?

Comment: @Serg that's correct that was the original behavior in 12.04

Comment: @Anwar I'm not sure what is is called technically I tend to call it expose even though that might not be the right name.

Comment: @LiamWilliam a lot of things changed since 12.04 , so I would assume that feature was removed. I'll see if anything can be done about it

Comment: @Serg Do you have any idea where the best place to look?  The bounty expires soonish.  First step is probably to see what version this changed in exactly.

Comment: @Serg you were the only response I got did you figure anything out if you mind me asking?

Comment: @LiamWilliam no, unfortunately I didn't find anything relevant so far :(

Comment: @LiamWilliam I only found "spread" option via shortcut, but your window has to be focused in order to do that. I've not found a way via click

Comment: Question: In 16.04 the single click on icon that has only single window minimizes the window. Do you want to keep that functionality  and activate expo only when active window changes ? or do you want to only have expo functionality and no minimizing ?

Comment: Back to my previous question above ^ . I don't think the minimize single window feature can be disabled. I can only make single-click expo work when you switch between windows. So for example, if you have chrome highlighted, then you click on terminal icon ( and it's a single window) , expo will be activated.

Comment: @Serg I don't care if the minimize single window feature works I will not use it.  Just as your example I believe you heard me right.

Comment: OK. I will polish my script and post it tomorrow, i suppose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Contents:

1. Overview
2. Script source
3. Additional notes

#### 1. Overview

As mentioned in the comments, this functionality apparently got removed since 12.04 and now click on the launcher icon minimizes the window (which apparently was a highly-requested feature, from what I can see in my online searches). However, there exists a keyboard to turn on expo for a single window, which is <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>. Knowing that, if we can detect click on the launcher or position of the cursor when window is raised , then we can simulate that single window expo via that keyboard shortcut. *The script below does exactly that.*

This is meant to be saved as `/usr/bin/single_click_expo.py` file and added to Startup Applications

[image]

#### 2. Script Source

Also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/SergKolo/sergrep/blob/master/single_window_expo.py)

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# Author: Serg Kolo
# Date: Sept 28, 2016
# Purpose: activates
# Depends: python3-gi
#          xdotool
# Written for: http://askubuntu.com/q/651188/295286

# just in case user runs this with python 2
from __future__ import print_function
import gi
gi.require_version('Gdk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import Gdk,Gio
import sys
import dbus
import subprocess

def run_cmd(cmdlist):
    """ Reusable function for running shell commands"""
    try:
        stdout = subprocess.check_output(cmdlist)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        print(">>> subprocess:",cmdlist)
        sys.exit(1)
    else:
        if stdout:
            return stdout

def gsettings_get(schema,path,key):
    """Get value of gsettings schema"""
    if path is None:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new(schema)
    else:
        gsettings = Gio.Settings.new_with_path(schema,path)
    return gsettings.get_value(key)


def get_launcher_object(screen):
    
    # Unity allows launcher to be on multiple
    # monitors, so we need to account for all 
    # window objects of the launcher
    launchers = []

    for window in screen.get_window_stack():
        xid = window.get_xid()
        command = ['xprop','-notype',
                   'WM_NAME','-id',str(xid)
        ]
        xprop = run_cmd(command).decode()
        title = xprop.replace("WM_NAME =","")
        if title.strip()  == '"unity-launcher"':
           launchers.append(window)
           #return window
    return launchers

def get_dbus(bus_type,obj,path,interface,method,arg):
    # Reusable function for accessing dbus
    # This basically works the same as 
    # dbus-send or qdbus. Just give it
    # all the info, and it will spit out output
    if bus_type == "session":
        bus = dbus.SessionBus() 
    if bus_type == "system":
        bus = dbus.SystemBus()
    proxy = bus.get_object(obj,path)
    method = proxy.get_dbus_method(method,interface)
    if arg:
        return method(arg)
    else:
        return method() 
 

def main():


    previous_xid = int()
    screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()

    while True:

        current_xid = screen.get_active_window().get_xid()
        if  int(current_xid) == previous_xid:
            continue
        previous_xid = int(current_xid)
        icon_size = gsettings_get(
                        'org.compiz.unityshell',
                        '/org/compiz/profiles/unity/plugins/unityshell/',
                        'icon-size')
        icon_size = int(str(icon_size))
        position = str(gsettings_get(
                       'com.canonical.Unity.Launcher',
                       None,
                       'launcher-position'))
        screen = Gdk.Screen.get_default()
        launcher_objs = get_launcher_object(screen)

        # for faster processing,figure out which launcher is used
        # first before running xdotool command. We also need
        # to account for different launcher positions (available since 16.04)
        pointer_on_launcher = None
        for launcher in launcher_objs:
            if 'Left' in position and  \
               abs(launcher.get_pointer().x) <= icon_size:
                  pointer_on_launcher = True
            elif 'Bottom' in position and \
               abs(launcher.get_pointer().y) <= icon_size:
                  pointer_on_launcher = True
            else:
               continue


        active_xid = int(screen.get_active_window().get_xid())
        
        application = get_dbus('session',
                               'org.ayatana.bamf',
                               '/org/ayatana/bamf/matcher',
                               'org.ayatana.bamf.matcher',
                               'ApplicationForXid',
                               active_xid)

        # Apparently desktop window returns empty application
        # we need to account for that as well
        if application:
            xids = list(get_dbus('session',
                            'org.ayatana.bamf',
                            application,
                            'org.ayatana.bamf.application',
                            'Xids',None))

        if pointer_on_launcher and\
           len(xids) == 1:
               run_cmd(['xdotool','key','Ctrl+Super+W'])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

#### 3. Additional notes

- It might be advisable to remap the shortcut to something other <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> , because in expo <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> in Expo corresponds to "close window" command. Potential issue here is that frequent switching may cause window closing. The script would have to be adjusted as well accordingly.

#### NOTE:

The script relies on `xdotool` utility. You must have it installed. Without `xdotool` it won't work, since `xdotool` is used to simulate keypresses. Install it via `sudo apt-get install xdotool`

Comment: I get `No module named gi`

Comment: @LiamWilliam You probably need to install `python3-gi` package. Odd, since it's like a standard module and comes with Ubuntu by default.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/q/159074/295286

Comment: What version of ubuntu are you on?

Comment: @LiamWilliam 16.04 LTS, but `python3-gi` also comes by default in 14.04 LTS. I don't know about earlier versions

Comment: Thank you for the response but I continue to get the error `ImportError: No module named gi`  If you want we could try https://www.teamviewer.com/en/

Comment: @LiamWilliam sorry, i can't use teamviewer right now. Did you install `python3-gi` ? Run `sudo apt-get install python3-gi`

Comment: I was doing python script.py instead of python3 script.py.  Now I am getting this error http://pastebin.com/raw/xhGuAHsg

Comment: @LiamWilliam sorry, that one is my bad - you also need `xdotool` for this. I should have mentioned that in the answer. Will edit in a minute.  Usually I try to minimize dependencies of my scripts , but in this case it's necessary

Comment: This doesn't seem to work on single click like I described.  Is there a way to detect if expose is active so if you click on one icon after another in the dock it doesn't glitch back in forth.

Comment: @LiamWilliam unfortunately no. There's no way to detect expo being active. Well, I tried my best here

Comment: Could you post a video of this working I can't get it to work at all.

Comment: @LiamWilliam sure, once I'm home, I'll make demo video and add link to it in this answer

Comment: So it appears no version of ubuntu worked the way I'm destribing I have tested everyone version of ubuntu back to 11 version so I'm not sure what I am remembering.